# Subseries converge

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I want to ask:
Let's say we have the series of non-negative terms $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ which is convergent.
Can I directly say that the series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_{2k}$  is convergent because all of its terms contain in the first serie which is convergent and they are non-negative?

And what about if they can be negative?

Comment: For the negative case look at $\sum_n(-1)^n/n$, then the even terms is $\sum_n1/(2n)=2\sum_n1/n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is true, because $0\leqslant\sum_{k=1}^na_{2k}\leqslant\sum_{k=1}^{2n}a_k$.

But if the $a_n$'s can be negative, then it is false. Consider the convergent series$$1-1+\frac12-\frac12+\frac13-\frac13+\cdots$$It converges, but$$-1-\frac12-\frac13-\cdots$$diverges.

Comment: So, if a serie's terms are a subset of the set of terms of a convergent serie and are non-negative I can say that the first serie also converges?

Comment: Written as it is, this assertion is false. The correct assumption is that the terms of the bigger series are positive. Otherwise you have counterexamples like the one given by José above.

Comment: @spyer Yes (assuming that the terms of the “big” series are non-negative).

Comment: Yes, I meant this. Thank you very much!!!