# Let {$x_n$} be such that $\lim \inf_{n \to \infty }|x_n|=0$. Prove that there exists a {$x_{n_{k}}$} where $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x_{n_{k}}$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> Problem: Let $\{x_n\}$ be such that $\displaystyle\lim \inf_{n \to \infty }|x_n|=0$. Prove that $\exists$ a subsequence $\{x_{n_{k}}\}$ where the subseries $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x_{n_{k}}$ converges.

I know that $\displaystyle\lim\inf_{n \to \infty } |x_n| = \sup_{n \geqslant 1} \inf_{k\geqslant n} |x_k|=0$.

However, I am confused as to how to take this to the limit of a series, and conclude that infinite series converges. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Pick your favourite converging positive series $y_n$ and choose $k_n$ increasing such that |$x_{k_n}| \le y_n$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Subseries converge](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2762486/subseries-converge)

Comment: It's sort of a contraposition of what _Nicole Orésme_ did to prove the harmonic series is divergent.

Comment: Also use `\{  \}` for $\{\;\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\displaystyle a_n=\inf_{j\geq n} |x_j|$. By hypothesis, $a_n \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. Let $\{b_k\}$ be a positive sequence such that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k <\infty.$ Obviously, $b_k \to 0$. Since $a_n \to 0$, for each $k$, there exists $n_k$ such that $a_{n_k}<b_k$. By definition, $b_k$ is not a lower bound for the set $A_{n_k}=\{|x_m| : m\geq n_k\}$. Hence, there exists $|x_{m(n_k)}|\in A_{n_k}$ such that $a_{n_k}\leq |x_{m(n_k)}|<b_k$.

Finally, by comparison, $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^\infty |x_{m(n_k)}|<\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k<\infty,$ so the convergence follows (absolutely).